# Libgdx Processing input in actor

Tags: java, android, libgdx

LibGDX. I aant to have an actor in a stage to get touch inputs. Had it working before adding in stage to code.

I can get the actor to draw to screen but after that, I'm not sure what to do.
`addListener` seems not to be working any more.

`Box.java`:

```
public class Box extends Actor {
   private MyGdxGame game;
ShapeRenderer renderer;

   private Vector3 pos;
   private int width, height;
   private Rectangle rect;
   private Vector3 color;

   public Box(MyGdxGame game) {
      super();
      this.game = game;
renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
// arbitrary x/y values
      pos = new Vector3(300, 300, 0);
      width = 300;
      height = 200;
      rect = new Rectangle(pos.x, pos.y, width, height);
      color = new Vector3();
      changeColor();

      addListener(new ClickListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int button, int pointer) {
            changeColor();
            return false;
         }
      });
   }

   private void changeColor() {
      Random rng = new Random();
      color.x = rng.nextInt(255) / 255f;
      color.y = rng.nextInt(255) / 255f;
      color.z = rng.nextInt(255) / 255f;
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
      super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);   
renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
      renderer.setColor(color.x, color.y, color.z, 1);
      renderer.rect(pos.x, pos.y, width, height);
      renderer.end();
   }

public void dispose() {
renderer.dispose();
}
}
```

MyGDXGame.java

```
public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {
   public OrthographicCamera camera;

   private Stage stage;

   @Override
   public void create() {
      camera = new OrthographicCamera();
      camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),  Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

      Box box = new Box(this);

      stage = new Stage();
      stage.addActor(box);

      Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
   }

   @Override
   public void render() {        
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      camera.update();

      stage.act();
      stage.draw();
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
      renderer.dispose();
   }

   @Override
   public void resize(int width, int height) {}

   @Override
   public void pause() {}

   @Override
   public void resume() {}
}
```

I removed Box's own position and size variables but now it's throwing all kinds of errors. Mainly `IllegalStateExceptions` and `IllegalAccessErrors`:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 16934
04-30 05:46:43.623 19181 19270 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.suchuu.box2dsquares, PID: 19181
04-30 05:46:43.623 19181 19270 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.IllegalStateException:
04-30 05:46:43.623 19181 19270 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.java:190)
04-30 05:46:43.623 19181 19270 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.suchuu.box2dsquares.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:25)
04-30 05:46:43.623 19181 19270 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:414)
04-30 05:46:43.623 19181 19270 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1571)
04-30 05:46:43.623 19181 19270 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1270)
```

`Box.java`:

```
public class Box extends Actor {
   private MyGdxGame game;
   ShapeRenderer renderer;
   private Vector3 color;

   public Box(MyGdxGame game) {
      super();
      this.game = game;
      renderer = new ShapeRenderer();

      setPosition(300, 300);
      setBounds(300, 300, 600, 500);

      color = new Vector3();
      changeColor();

    this.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

      this.addListener(new ClickListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int button, int pointer) {
            changeColor();
            event.handle();
            return false;
         }
      });
   }

   private void changeColor() {
    Random rng = new Random();
      color.x = rng.nextInt(255) / 255f;
      color.y = rng.nextInt(255) / 255f;
      color.z = rng.nextInt(255) / 255f;
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
      super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

      renderer.begin();
    renderer.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
      renderer.setColor(color.x, color.y, color.z, 1);
      renderer.rect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
      renderer.end();
   }

   public void dispose() {
      renderer.dispose();
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this question spark nobodies interest?

Comment: What exact code did you add?

Comment: You're setting width height and pos to Box class. Remove these fields and set Actor's variables

Comment: Tried to change to using super.width / height but errors continue to occur...

Comment: Oh, I forgot to remove pos. Okay, gimmi a moment... Coding...

Comment: Okay. So. I removed Box's own position and size vars and am now trying to use the parent class's feilds. Surely this has become a problem with how I work with pure Java? It's been a long while - I've forgotten how to do this... Check the edit on 1st post for details. Thanks.

Comment: Upload your code to github so i can clone and look into this

Comment: I'll be honest. My noob level is very high. I neved learned how to use github - and now I don'w have a working laptop, I'm forced to work from my phone. But I did manage to make a repository and upload the two java files... https://github.com/StudioGilliam/Box2DSquares

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
renderer.begin();
renderer.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
```

To

```
renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. This problem is now fixed. I learn a little more each day.